# Create sequentially evenly space instances when points increase or decrease using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, instances

I'm trying to create sequentially evenly spaced instances when points increase or decrease using geometry nodes.

Example: When the amount of points change the arc instance should increase (evenly spaced) sequentially along the x-axis.

At the moment it tries to limit it to a specific length and fills it in. I'm trying to get it to continue being added on the x-axis sequentially while being evenly spaced.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would first have to create the curve/points at which instances are to be created, and then choose at which ones instantiation should actually occur.

Something like this:

[image]

And if you want to control the even distribution from the center, you could use the following setup:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>